# Program for automatically moving files to various folders

Tags: file-management

Is there a (Windows) program where I can e.g. drag and drop many files, or which processes all files in a folder, in such a way that based on some rules they end up in a specific folder.

E.g. all PDF files go into the PDF folder, but each PDF starting with 'Arduino' is moved to the ArduinoPDF folder, so not only based on the extension, but also on name or possibly other attributes.